# Mongo Data API, C# code syntax when trying to use EJSON

Tags: c#, mongodb, syntax

I am trying to set up a simple API call from a c# application to the Mongo Atlas Data API.

According to their documentation (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api-data-formats/#date) the API will use JSON and EJSON (Mongo extended Json) but does not mention BSON as being accepted.

The problem is, that when I want to represent some of the special commands within the json object in C# there is a syntax issue because they represent these commands with a $ symbol.

Here is their example :

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/<Data API App ID>/endpoint/data/v1/action/insertOne' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/ejson' \
  --header 'api-key: <Data API Key>' \
  --data-raw '{
      "dataSource": "<cluster name>",
      "database": "<database name>",
      "collection": "<collection name>",
      "document": {
        "createdAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1638551310749" } }
      }
  }'
```

Which I have attempted to convert to my use case:

```
            var data = new 
            {
                dataSource = ClusterName,
                database = "mydb",
                collection = "contact",
                filter = new { contactSalesforceReference = contact.AccountId },
                update = new {
                    $set = new {
                        contactFirstName = contact.Firstname,
                        contactLastName = contact.Lastname,
                        contactEmail = contact.Email,
                        version = "1.0",
                        dateUpdated = new { $date = new { DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.000+00:00") } }
                    } 
                },
                upsert = false
            };
```

As you can see the dateUpdated field will cause a syntax issue, not to mention the $set as well.

How do you get around this?

Comment: Use real classes instead of anonymous classes and add proper JsonProperty Attributes for the names?

Comment: @Ralf I thought about that but $set acts more like a command than a property so its class would always change depending on the request being made. For example just updating the email instead of all other fields within the $set.

Comment: That can still be a class will all fields possible and letting the serializer only serialize things that are not null.

Comment: Doesn't the standard MongoDB Driver do all of that for you already?

Comment: The driver does but you cannot use the driver without whitelisting the IP of the sender and since we will be using this app for third parties to connect in, that would be an administrate nightmare to maintain. I will go the POCO route and see how it goes, thanks!